# Cordova java plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to write a Java application that implements a printer interface and use this java code as the native element for multiple platforms (osx, win) inside a cordova plugin?

Comment: you should provide native implementation for each platform if you want to get cross-platform version of your plugin

Comment: Ok good. This example doesn't run on my machine https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello, `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-SE, 10.2 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=163):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
logPath: /Users/svencornelis/Development/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log`

Comment: you can find solution for this issue here - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4657, looks like  permissions problem

Comment: Saved the day! http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2015/11/ionic-invalid-device-state-error-with-xcode-7-solved

Comment: Is there a OSX example plugin?